# Trac/Apache Displays Script Contents (WSGI)

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi, trac, wsgi

I am struggling with a new Trac 1.0.3 install (from source after having same issue installing via `easy_install`).

- Debian 7.8
- Apache 2.2.22
- Python 2.7.3
- Genshi 0.6
- Sqlite 3.7.13
- WSGI 3.3

I created the Trac environment in `/var/trac` and `/var/trac/cgi-bin` holds `trac.wsgi`.  I've updated Apache... `LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so` and my site's conf...

```
WSGIScriptAlias /trac /var/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi

<Directory /var/trac/cgi-bin>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /trac>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

My `/var/trac/log/trac.log` (which is empty) is configured in `trac.ini`...

```
[logging]
log_file = /var/trac/log/trac.log
log_level = DEBUG
log_type = file
```

My Apache error log...

```
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0x7f4d8661f0f0 rmm=0x7f4d8661f148 for VHOST: hostname.example.net
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] APR LDAP: Built with OpenLDAP LDAP SDK
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] LDAP: SSL support available
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [debug] mod_wsgi.c(10080): mod_wsgi (pid=12945): Socket for 'My-WSGIDaemonProcess' is '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.12945.0.1.sock'.
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12951): Starting process 'My-WSGIDaemonProcess' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12951): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] Server built: Dec 23 2014 22:48:32
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [debug] worker.c(1757): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12952): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12953): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12952): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12951): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 29 18:38:46 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12953): Attach interpreter ''.
```

A browser request in Apache's access log...

```
1.2.3.4 - - [29/Jan/2015:18:44:20 -0500] "GET /trac HTTP/1.1" 304 188 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
```

***The problem:*** Apache is serving the *contents* of `/var/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi`... I see the Python code.

I don't know where I went wrong but your help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

***UPDATE 1:*** As you can see the above info surrounds making a `GET /trac` request.  I have found though making a `GET /trac/login` request results in Apache throwing an `HTTP 500`.

***UPDATE 2:*** I disabled the mis-configured LDAP auth and the `HTTP 500` errors in `UPDATE 1` are now `HTTP 404`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem...

Apache configuration...

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi

<Directory /var/trac/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride None
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Options ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Compare this config to that posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Within your cgi-bin directives, try adding "ExecCGI" option and adding the cgi-script handler:

```
<Directory /var/trac/cgi-bin>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
```

Comment: I added `Options` and `SetHandler` as suggested - seems to have no impact.  I also tried, rather than `SetHandler cgi-script`, `SetHandler wsgi-script` - again, no difference.

Comment: Another stab in the dark.  Is the trac.wsgi file executable?

`chmod 755 /var/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi`

Comment: Yes, `trac.wsgi` is owned by `www-data` and is executable.